UE4 camera blend when switching between 2 characters
I'm trying to set up a system in UE4.27 where I can switch between 2 characters. It works but when I tried to include a camera blend, it still switches character but the camera just jumps and doesn't blend. Both of the characters have camera components with auto activation,
Any suggestions?


https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this

It could be that you have another script running, which updates the camera position, and thus overriding the blend.
